# Optionally bypass required fields for content type

Tags: 8, nodes, forms

I'm sorry that I don't have more to share, as far as code goes, but I keep hitting dead ends and am not sure how I should be going about this. I keep trying very D7 methods, but I think that's not only bad for D8, but possibly not possible.

What I want is this:
- I'm looking for a submit button (but not THE submit, something more like "draft") to be able to save a node, but also ignore all required fields (except for title of course, 'cause that's absolutely necessary.)
- This is for something like a draft, where it only needs to make sure all required fields are entered when finally submitting

Can anyone give general guidance on how I might be able to do this? I keep thinking of trying to add a validation function/override the form's validation function, but that seems to be hitting a dead end for me and also seems like it may be too D7.

Comment: The new content moderation module in core might work for this.  I know it has a draft option like workbench moderation in 7.  Not sure if it bypasses validation though.

Comment: The "draft" option only seems to be to keep the thing in an unpublished status with a "draft" state for the workflow. Nothing else really different.

If I remember correctly, they claimed what you're thinking on a contrib module, and said it wouldn't be ported to D8; but the functionality does not seem to be there.